# PCA + k-means results in small clusters

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, k-means, pca

I am working on a market segmentation problem. I have 100+ variables that I can reduce to 31 factors through PCA. When I put this into a k-means model, I obtain solutions that have two clusters with with slightly less than half the sample each, then two or three other clusters with one or two.

Usually, those one off clusters are the result of outliers, but is there any other way in preprocessing beyond PCA I can avoid clusters with one to two observations?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is remove outliers before doing the clustering and the PCA. This will make your algorithm look for real clusters rather than outliers in your data.

There is multiple technics to remove outliers, you can do this the old way by removing observation with abnormal values (which can be very efficient). If a feature is too far from the global distribution of the feature, you can consider that it's an outlier.

You can also try unsupervised algorithms like IsolationForest or Local Outlier Factor. I usually use the first one, Since it looks at all the variables in the same time rather than looking at each variable separately. It has prooven to be very efficient until now.

Comment: Thank you. This yielded more reasonable clusters, but through  various evaluation techniques I've found that the optimal solution is k=2, which is not an entirely useful solution. Are there other techniques to yield more clusters?

Comment: Even if the optimal solution is 2 (which is a frequent case), you can choose to run your algorithm with more clusters, especially if it doesn't hurt your performance by much.

Comment: That's useful, thanks. One other technique I've read is to do a first pass with k-means then augment with hierarchical cluster, but I can't find any literature on this. Is it possible to combine these methods?